# Windows 10 File Explorer Transfer Speed issue

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, performance, external-hard-drive, truecrypt

I move a lot of files from one place to another and with a specific combo of 2 of my storage devices I noticed a strange behavior:
When moving Data from one SSD to another SSD Transfer speeds are usually 300-400MB/s (Max: 500MB/s).

but when moving data from one SSD to an HDD, the data Transferring speeds fluctuate randomly. Ive noticed that in regular intervals, the speed which is shown in the File Explorer goes up to 1GB/s, doubled the claimed maximum speed of the SSD, and way higher then the claimed 100MB/s of the HDD. I've looked into it and the average speed is always ~90MB/s. Is this some kind of error in the file Explorer, or has it something to do with the storage devices itself? How to fix it?

Info:

OS: Windows 10 Home

Encryption Software: Truecrypt 7.1a (Do **NOT** comment that it has security issues)

Storage Device referred to as "HDD": https://www.amazon.de/dp/B0713WPGLL

Storage Device referred to as "SSD": https://www.amazon.de/dp/B07QND4VZ6

CPU: Intel i7, 4 cores 2.5GHz

RAM: 32GB DDR3, 1333MHz

GPU: GTX 980M (20GB Version)

Data beeing transfered:
.rm
.mov
.mp4
.avi
.AVCHD
.WMV
(all in video form)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmVwT.png)

Comment: Note: Truecrypt has not received any updates since 2014 and even has a big fat red banner on the top of [its sourceforge site](http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/) saying: "WARNING: Using TrueCrypt is not secure as it may contain unfixed security issues" and "WARNING: Using TrueCrypt is not secure

You should download TrueCrypt only if you are migrating data encrypted by TrueCrypt." on the bottom.

Comment: The speed shown in the File Explorer is how fast data is sent to the used API. because of caches and other factors it can be totally different to the actual writing speed. Check Windows task manager on the tab "Performance" to see the actual disk speed. BTW: For what reason do you still use Truecrypt, usually VeraCrypt should be compatible and thus the better option.